# Problem with mouseListener and while loop

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, mouselistener

There's a problem I'm trying to do: I'm supposed to use mouseListeners and on mouse click do one of the following:

1. If clicked on empty space (my program extends GraphicsProgram) add a circle and make it random color.
2. If clicked on a circle, make the circle flicker (from 5 possible colors) until it reaches color Green.

```
//instance variables:
Color[] arr = new Color[] { Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK, Color.YELLOW };
private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        GObject object = getElementAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (object == null) {
            addCircle(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
        else {
            GOval oval = (GOval) object;
            colorCircle(oval);          
        }
    }

private void colorCircle(GOval circle) {
        while (true) {
            int rand = rgen.nextInt(0, 4);
            circle.setFillColor(arr[rand]);
            pause(DELAY);
            if (rand == 0)
                break;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that while clicking the circle, it doesn't flicker, it just outputs green. Increasing DELAY results in just delayed output of the green. So it skips coloring other colors, until it reaches green.

I'm using Stanford's libraries for this one (I have to use them for this problem).

P.S. I've tested while loop without mouse click and it works just fine, so the mouseListener is definitely the one causing the problem. What could be the issue and how to overcome it?

Comment: The issue is that you are blocking the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). This is the thread that invokes your `mouseClicked` and therefore your `colorCircle` methods. This is the same thread that does the painting / updating of the GUI. But it can't paint / update the GUI if it is busy waiting and doing the work from your `colorCircle`.

Comment: @maloomeister I figured it would be a problem with threads, but this problem was on University exam and we haven't learned threads yet. So is there a way to rewrite this without using additional threads?

Comment: I think a [swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) is what you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by trying to run the code from mouseClicked. Instead of that I created boolean mouseClicked and made it true when mouse is clicked on a circle. Then I called the flickering method in run (same as main). Here's the full code:

```
public class BlankClass extends GraphicsProgram {

    private final static int CIRCLE_D = 40;
    private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();   
    private final static int DELAY = 50;
    private volatile boolean  clickedCircle = false;
    Color[] arr = new Color[] { Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.BLACK, Color.YELLOW };


    public void init() {
        addMouseListeners();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (clickedCircle) {
                colorCircle();
                clickedCircle = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        GObject object = getElementAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (object == null) {
            addCircle(e.getX(), e.getY());
        } else {
            oval = (GOval) object;
            clickedCircle = true;
        }
    }

    private void addCircle(int x, int y) {
        int centerX = (x - CIRCLE_D / 2);
        int centerY = (y - CIRCLE_D / 2);
        GOval oval = new GOval(centerX, centerY, CIRCLE_D, CIRCLE_D);
        oval.setFilled(true);
        oval.setFillColor(rgen.nextColor());
        add(oval);
    }

    private void colorCircle() {
        while (true) {
            int rand = rgen.nextInt(0, 4);
            oval.setFillColor(arr[rand]);
            if (rand == 0)
                break;
            pause(DELAY);
        }
    }
}
```

It's important to set the boolean clickedCircle as volatile, otherwise compilator might ignore the conditional in while(true) loop (that was another issue I faced).